# mongo Aggregate and return results by months

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have this...

```
$group: {
        '_id': this.userId,
        'hours': {
            $sum: '$hours'
        },
        'magazines': {
            $sum: '$magazines'
        },
        'brochures': {
            $sum: '$brochures'
        },
        'books': {
            $sum: 'books'
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        hours: '$hours',
        magazines: '$magazines',
        brochures: '$brochures',
        books: '$books'
    }
```

... which returns the sum of the above fields.

What I want to do is, return the total sum of, say, hours for a particular user, grouped into months.

Something like:

```
January:
    userId:
        hours: 10
        magazines: 10
        ....
February:
    userId:
        hours:2
        magazines: 2
etc
```

Comment: use [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) date operator of mongo.

split your date in month, then group by `userId` and `month`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that works. Answer on [MongoDB-User group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/mongodb-user/nWTv78AEtNs):

```
[{
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $month: "$createdAt"
            },
            hours: {
                $sum: "$hours",
            },
            magazines: {
                $sum: "$magazines"
            },
            brochures: {
                $sum: "$brochures"
            },
            books: {
                $sum: "$books"
            }
        }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following aggregation pipeline which uses the **[date aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)** **[`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year)** and **[`$month`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month)** to get the total sums for the given attributes per user grouped into months:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "userId": "$userId"
                "year": { "$year": "$date" }
                "month" { "$month": "$date" }
            },
            'hours': {
                $sum: '$hours'
            },
            'magazines': {
                $sum: '$magazines'
            },
            'brochures': {
                $sum: '$brochures'
            },
            'books': {
                $sum: 'books'
            }
        ]
    }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

To get the exact schema where you convert the month and userId values to keys, use the **[`map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/)** method from the cursor returned by the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method:

```
var result = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).map(function (doc){
    var obj = {};
    obj[doc._id.month][doc._id.userId]["hours"] = doc.hours;
    obj[doc._id.month][doc._id.userId]["magazines"] = doc.magazines;
    obj[doc._id.month][doc._id.userId]["brochures"] = doc.brochures;
    obj[doc._id.month][doc._id.userId]["books"] = doc.books;

    return obj;
});

printjson(result);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it soon.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. I posted the actual one that worked below